# Filtering huge quantities of data with combinations of logical expressions

Tags: search, filter, redis, bigdata, hyperloglog

I have huge quantities of data represented as (for example) -

User ID | Gender |  Location | Type of User

There may be more columns depending on the use case. The location is denoted by a pincode.

I recently read about HyperLogLog and the Redis implementation. So for example, I can conveniently get a count for just male users or users of a certain "type" and I can merge these hyperloglog sets to answer questions like -

> Count of Unique Users who are male and of type A

The problem is when I have to deal with columns like location. I cannot store sets for each possible pincode. So a question like -

> Count of unique users who are male and belong to pincodes A and B

are hard to answer using this method.

Using HyperLogLog or redis is not a constraint. I am open to use any tool available provided it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a log analysis tool which allows arbitrary queries, such as Splunk or one of its [competitors](https://www.quora.com/Who-are-the-biggest-direct-competitors-to-Splunk)

It should be noted that the general case of this problem (in which you allow any arbitrary query over lots of collected data, and additionally the data is high dimensional) is very difficult. It's a good idea to check if your requirements can be cut down (i.e., is there actually a small number of particular conditions you'd like to count? If so, just make dedicated counters for them).